# What kind of function is this in Swift?

Tags: swift, syntax

```
Struct Something{
    static let default: [String] = {
        return Myparse()
    }()
    private static func Myparse() -> [String]{
...
    }
}
```

Can we pass parameters into parse() if we want? I have tried to look up in Apple's documentation and online tutorial but still no luck? Thank you.

Comment: from which class?

Comment: `parse()` is simply a function that returns a String. If it accepts input parameters, then you can pass one to it.

Comment: You can command+click on `parse` and "go tot definition" to see its definition. Then you will be able to determine whether you can pass arguments to it by looking at its signature.

Comment: Just update the code so that you guys can have a closer look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard static property which is initialized with the return value of that function. In this case it will call `parse()`, and the return value of that will be the value of the property.

You cannot pass arguments to parse “from the outside” of this function. But you can of course change the body of this function if you have access to this source code.

Answer (score -5):

I think this can help on how to declare variable same with that one. https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/all-about-properties-in-swift-d618481b1cc1

By the way, you can't use **`default`** as a variable name, it's a reserved word.

You can pass data in **parse()**, but it depends on what data you pass:

[image]

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers and screenshots of code!

Comment: My bad @Rishav, this is noted.

Comment: BTW by not editing your answer to get rid of the link and the image, you are not giving people the opportunity to reverse their downvotes.